# Как определить работает ли сайт?

Tags: php

У меня есть база сайтов, из неё хочу удалить те сайты, которые не работают, т.е. соединения не будет вообще. Знаю, что нужно как то проверять ответ от сервера, но точно не знаю( Подскажите пож-та.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если домен делигируется, и даже если сайт не работает, то ping пройдет, так что это не вариант... Надо отправить запрос и получить ответ от сайта...если ответом будет "200 ОК" то сайт работает...Если ответ с кодом 404 значт не отвечает сайт...

Comment: а если хоста уже нету, то будет не 404 а другая ошибка, я бы даже сказал что если есть 404 то сайт то жив, а вот конкретная страничка недоступна

Comment: 404 отсутствует страница, но сайт доступен!

Answer (score 1):

коммандой `ping` думаю проще всего. Если на php, то через `exec`

Comment: Спасибо, щас проверю

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 1):

можно еще командой curl из к.строки  для точности :) 
         curl -I hashcode.com 
   вернет заголовки, если http ответ 200 то все хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

В общем полистал сайты, пришёл к такому коду:

```
function TestSite($url){
$Headers = @get_headers($url);
// проверяем ли ответ от сервера с кодом 200 - ОК
if(strpos('200', $Headers[0])) {
return true; // Файл существует
} else {
return false; // Файл не найден
}
}
```

Т.е., сделал способом **Ёхарный Бабай**. Всем спасибо.

Comment: метод ненадёжный, написал выше почему, уж если на то пошло то надо ловить ошибку 503/504